# How to apply the same font style in renewcommands

Tags: fonts

I am define one command like

```
\newcommand\specialhead{\fontspec{Helvetica}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont {Speciality Section:}\break}
```

In such cases i am using the renewcommand like

```
\renewcommand{\speciahead}{Meta section:}
```

In this case my required output the font style like

```
\fontspec{Helvetica}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
```

should not be changed in Meta section.

But the fontstyle changed. I am manually given font style command once again. My required output is i am not mannually given the font style. Please advice

Comment: You've asked a whole host of questions, with a request for some context via a minimal example each time. Please do this again...

Comment: \fontspec should not be used here. Define a new fontfamily like this: `\newfontfamily\helvetica{Helvetica}[<fontspec options>]`. See the fontspec documentation, page 7f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it simpler to define `\specialhead` as

```
\newcommand\specialhead[1]{{\helv\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont #1}}
```

with `\helv` being

```
\newfontfamily{\helv}{Helvetica}
```

and then use it as

```
\specialhead{Meta section:}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\helv}{Helvetica}

\newcommand\specialhead[1]{{\helv\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont #1}}

\begin{document}

\specialhead{Speciality Section:} some text

\specialhead{Meta section:} some text

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Please, avoid using the `\fontspec` command in the body of the document. Use `\newfontfamily`, instead: it's ***much*** more efficient.

Comment: I avoid the \fontspec coding and using the \newfontfamily.